# How to re-deploy stack when getting 'resource already exists in stack' error, without deleting the resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to add a 'get' function to an already existing DynamoDB table in AWS. I added a yml file for the table, and when I tried to deploy the stack, it said that the resource for my table already exists.

In the past I have deleted the table when this happens and then redeployed the stack, but in this case I do not want to delete the table and don't know how else to fix the problem.

My first issue was that I had defined the table's schema incorrectly in the YML file. Then when I redefined it I had the issue with the resource already existing in the stack.

My error:

> Serverless Error ---------------------------------------
>       An error occurred: ConsumersTable - dev-con already exists in stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-ea

Comment: Could you figure this one out? I am getting error in publishing Lambda Function

Comment: @awsquestion126734 It would have been helpful if you also posted an example of your YAML code.

Answer (score 61):

I experienced this issue myself and contacted AWS support.  It seems that CloudFormation associates the logical ID with the resource, for example (using IAM as an example but many resources are the same):

```
exampleLogicalId:
  Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
  Properties:
    PolicyDocument:
      ManagedPolicyName: exampleName
  ...
```

Here, the resource gets created with a custom name (`exampleName` in this case).  As long as the logical ID (`exampleLogicalId`) remains unchanged, CloudFormation will recognise that the resource has already been created and will update it as necessary.

However if you change the logical ID (as happened to me when using CDK, because it auto-generates these logical IDs) then CloudFormation thinks it needs to create a new resource.  But because the name already exists, and for this resource type the names must be unique, there is a conflict and the creation fails.  This seems to be because CloudFormation creates all new resources before deleting any removed ones.

The solution is to either 1) put the logical ID back to what it originally was so CloudFormation recognises it as an 'update' rather than a 'create', or 2) change the unique part (the `exampleName` in this example) to be something unique.

Changing the name (or whatever the unique field is for the resource in question) can be a convenient option, because it will create the new resource and associate it with the new logical ID, then delete the old resource if that logical ID no longer exists in your CloudFormation template.  You can then rename the resource back to what you wanted originally (keeping the same logical ID) and deploy a second time, and CloudFormation will recognise it as an update operation, and rename the resource back to what you wanted the first time.

Just be aware that doing this will not perform an update, but rather a delete-then-create.  So if your resource has data (e.g. DynamoDB table with data, IAM policy already attached to roles, Parameter Store entry with a value entered) you may need to recreate this data for the new resource.

Comment: Nice fix, I did the same myself, I am improving some deployments to multiple environments and automating the deployment with bitbucket pipelines, basically, when this happens, I normally go to the yml file, change the name of the resource to a prefix for instance, deploy it and then revert the changes to deploy it again.

Comment: The question says "I do not want to delete the table" so I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: @CarlWalsh Well it does - you have to put your old logical ID back in again so Cfn recognises it as an update instead of a create, then the stack will deploy without error.

Comment: Omg this is the reason! I had broken my head countless times because of this. I confirm the answer is correct, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 7):

You can **import existing resources** to CloudFormation (CFN):

- [Bringing Existing Resources Into CloudFormation Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html)

`AWS::DynamoDB::Table` is also [one of the resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html) that supports the import operation.

Thus, if you don't want to delete your existing table, you can import it into CFN. Then you can **manage it using CFN** as would any other table created from scratch in CFN.

Hopes this helps.